# Connecting through Abu Dhabi with Etihad and Virgin Australia

Tags: etihad, syd, jnb, abu-dhabi, auckland

I'm looking at a flight from Johannesburg, South Africa to Auckland, New Zealand. The route is Johannesburg to Abu Dhbai with Etihad Airways (EY). Then there is a connecting flight to Sydney operated by Virgin Australia but the flight has an EY code (Etihad) Then the final flight is operated by Air New Zealand but also has an EY code.

Will get all my boarding passes in Johannesburg and will my luggage will be checked in all the way through to Auckland?

Comment: Given this is urgent, wouldn't you be best off ringing your airline to ask them?

Comment: I wonder how long that flight is in total!

Answer (score 2):

If you can purchase all three flights as one ticket, your luggage will definitely be checked all the way to Auckland, and you will most probably get all your boarding passes at JNB.  If you don't, you can pick them up at transfer desks along the way in Abu Dhabi or Sydney; you will definitely not need to go through Immigration or Customs at any point along the way.

But as Gagravarr says, if this is urgent and you want a definitive answer, call the airline instead of trusting random people on the Intertubes!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will, because your flight (although a code share) is flown by one carrier Etihad - I am also willing to bet it has a 4 digit flight number.

Once you arrive in Abu Dhabi you will spend time at the transit lounge and board your next flight.

At check-in, you will definitely be given two boarding passes Johannesburg - Abu Dhabi, Abu Dhabi - Sydney; and also possibly the Sydney - Auckland boarding pass.

In either case, your bags will be checked through to New Zealand.

The reason you may not be given a pass for the final leg at Johannesburg is because sometimes the flight reservation systems don't have the aircraft data to issue seats. In this case you'll pick up your boarding pass at the transfer desk in Sydney.

This is rare, but does happen.

However in all circumstances you will clear customs and immigration in Auckland and pick up your luggage there.